# Cannot delete a database object after restarting the application

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

We have a Java application that uses Hibernate and a MySQL database. Delete transactions appear to work fine at first. But, if we exit our application and restart it, we are no longer able to delete anything from the database. We do not get any errors, the entries just don't delete. We can still create all and edit most entities.

I know that there are a lot of implementation-related reasons why this wouldn't work. However, we are not Hibernate experts and this code is built on foundation made a couple of years ago. At the very least, we need some guidance about the kinds of things to look for. I also apologize that I can't post any real code, but I could come up with some snippets if necessary.

So, what could cause this problem? Where do I begin? Is this a session problem of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would check if all connections to the DB are released on the application restart. If some connections are pending, you might encounter different problems.

Comment: How can I check that? I assume that's something in MySQL itself?

Comment: try this select {show status like 'Conn%';} this shows the number of active connections. Measure them before the application starts and after you stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Start with looking into DELETE statements as generated after restart. Wild guess is that these are using WHERE clause, for which there are no records in DB.

Comment: Any easy way to check that? We use Hibernate, so it just looks like an regular POJO operation to me.

Comment: Look for `show_sql` here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional